# add y axis label to NVD3 Multi-Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to add axis labels to a NVD3 Multi-Bar Chart, but it only seems to work for the x axis. Is there any way around this?

I have set up an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/msts1jha/2/

```
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();

chart.xAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

chart.yAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

chart.xAxis.axisLabel("x axis");
chart.yAxis.axisLabel("y axis");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `yAxis` is hidden, set the left margin on your chart, and it will work.

Try this :

```
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart().margin({left: 100});
```

More info regarding margins have a look [here](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/multiBarChart.js#L15)

Hope it helps

Comment: Great, thanks! I ended up using ```chart.yAxis.axisLabel(scope.ylab).axisLabelDistance(40)``` as well to decrease the spacing between the axis and the label.